# Which is the best alternative for CSS cross-browser layout?

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser

I am looking to have a layout (like example below) avoiding to use frameworks like Foundation/Bootstrap but at the same time that allows me to use at least in IE10, Firefox, Chrome.

I was seeing CSS Grid but this is not supported in IE10.

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap 3 supports IE 10, so you can just take a look at their grid approach and do something similar. If you can't be bothered, then use a table.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?

```css
.row {
  
  max-width: 114rem;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  }
  
  .row:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 8rem; 
    }
    
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    }
  .row [class^="col-"] {
    float: left; 
   }
    .row [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 6rem; 
    }
    
  .row .col-1-of-2 {
    width: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2); 
    background-color: orange;
    }
    
  .row .col-1-of-3 {
    width: calc((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3); 
    background-color: orange;
    }
    
  .row .col-2-of-3 {
    width: calc(2 * ((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3) + 6rem); 
    background-color: orange;
    }
    
  .row .col-1-of-4 {
    width: calc((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4); 
    background-color: orange;
    }
    
  .row .col-2-of-4 {
    width: calc(2 * ((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4) + 6rem); 
    background-color: orange;
    }
    
  .row .col-3-of-4 {
    width: calc(3 * ((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4) + 2 * 6rem); 
    background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<section class="grid-test">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-2">
                    Col 1 of 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-2">
                    Col 1 of 2
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-3">
                    Col 1 of 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-3">
                    Col 1 of 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-3">
                    Col 1 of 3
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-3">
                    Col 1 of 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-of-3">
                    Col 2 of 3
                </div>
           </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                    Col 1 of 4
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                    Col 1 of 4
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                    Col 1 of 4
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                        Col 1 of 4
                </div>                
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                    Col 1 of 4
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                    Col 1 of 4
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-of-4">
                    Col 2 of 4
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-4">
                    Col 1 of 4
                </div>
                <div class="col-3-of-4">
                    Col 3 of 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Wow, that works! although I did not imagine how complicate could be handle something like that.

Comment: so you simply re-create a small version of Boostrap .. so better use bootstrap in this case